# c++ How to only enable number input

Tags: c++

***How can i make it so that the user can only enter numbers? if they were to enter a letter the program breaks.***

```
cin >> num1;
cin >> num2;

cout << "the sum is" << num1 + num2;
```

Comment: You could give your user one of these: http://www.kos.ie/560-large_default/kinesis-freestyle2-keypad.jpg

Comment: I quite like this one although it doesn't address the problem: https://www.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/computer-keyboard-reduced-layout-binary-input-171645659

Comment: Lol yeah i wish.